# Javascript EventListener event delay?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, delay, addeventlistener

When i scroll really fast through my page, the event call backs tend to take a bit of time to catch up. I have used both scroll and wheel but still the same issue. When i hit a specific point on my page i want css to change and when i scroll really fast the css takes a half second to change making the experience laggy.

```
component.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, {passive: true});
component.addEventListener('wheel', this.handleScroll, {passive: true});
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the effect without javascript listeners?

Comment: well paste handleScroll function it seems your logic is slow not the events themselfs. Also a throttle would be a good choice since the these events fire a lot i suspect you are calculating the same thing again and again and this is making things laggy